# FGallery is overriding all rotation methods in my other views

Tags: ios, rotation, screen-rotation

So I have incorporated Mr. Grant Davis' [FGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) into my app for a photo gallery.  It works great other than it is overriding all my rotation methods in my other views and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to stop it.  Here's a snippet from FGallery's [FGalleryViewController](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone/blob/master/FGallery/Classes/FGalleryViewController.m) that handles the gallery:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (FGallery)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

   if([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[FGalleryViewController class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    // we need to support at least one type of auto-rotation we'll get warnings.
    // so, we'll just support the basic portrait.
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) ? YES : NO;
}
```

I have tried changing the line:

```
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) ? YES : NO;
```

but that forces all views to that specific orientation.  Some of my views allow for rotation and some do not.  So I guess my question is, how can I alter this line to allow rotation in some views and not in others?  I'm drawing a blank this morning!!

Any help or ideas here would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm gonna go ahead and answer my own question.

The answer is to remove the code that overrides the rotation:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (FGallery)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[FGalleryViewController class]]) 
    {
        return YES;
    }

    // we need to support at least one type of auto-rotation we'll get warnings.
    // so, we'll just support the basic portrait.
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) ? YES : NO;
}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // see if the current controller in the stack is a gallery
    if([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[FGalleryViewController class]])
    {
        FGalleryViewController *galleryController = (FGalleryViewController*)self.visibleViewController;
        [galleryController resetImageViewZoomLevels];
    }
}

@end
```

And call:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

within `@implementation FGalleryViewController`

Hopefully this helps someone else out that needs it.